# Badge "Electorate"

Tags: discussion, voting, badges, electorate-badge

I've earned a new badge - in the

> Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned

and Badge description this

> You've earned the "Electorate" badge (Voted on 600 questions and 25%
>   or more of total votes are on questions).

written down - I think it's kinda wrong or is it just me?

Edit: My Problem here was, that it was written to close together - a seperation like this would be nice:

> Voted on at least 600 question while at least 25% of your total votes
>   are on questions.

Comment: How is it _"wrong"_?

Comment: 600 votes on questions - 25% on questions?

Comment: __At least 25%__ of your __total__ vote count has to be on questions. Say, you voted on 600 questions and on 1200 answers, 33% of your votes are on questions.

Comment: If I vote on 600 questions, that would be 100%

Comment: If you vote on 600 questions, **and only 600 question** that would be 100% of total votes. If you have 600 votes on questions and 3600 votes total then percentage would be less.

Comment: Technically it is correct but the description should be improved to be less confusing.

Comment: @Miszy: _How_ is that description confusing? And how'd you suggest to improve it?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think the easiest solution is to make the word **total** bold.

Comment: So, basically, that means the description wasn't read properly. Which means this is just a case of ["PEBCAK"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK)

Comment: I´m not a native english speaker... So yeah maybe you are right...

Comment: Updated question with seperation example

Comment: Should't it also say "while at least 25% of your total votes" ("your", not "the")?

Comment: I think adding a simple `your` will help making the phrase a little less ambiguous: `Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of your total votes are on questions`

Comment: Was about to make this exact same question. The description is indeed confusing. I think adding "your" as suggested would improve the clarity of the description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks perfectly fine to me. You:

- Voted on 600 questions and
- *25% or more of **total votes*** are on questions

So you voted 600 times on questions. Those 600 votes make up at least 25% of all your votes on any type of post, so you voted at most 2400 times with 1800 votes on answers instead.

Comment: I think I just read to fast - From my reading it sounded like vote on 600 questions - 600 of 25% have to be on questions...but you are right.

Comment: For those who are not native English speakers, the `total` word might be misinterpreted as 25% of those 600 votes, and not 25% of `your` votes.

Answer (score 5):

At least 25% of your **total** vote count has to be on questions.

Say, you voted on `600` questions and on `1200` answers, 33% of your votes are on questions.
That's 33% of a **total** of 1800 votes.

The only improvement I could suggest is to make the word "total" in that badge's description **bold**.

Comment: And we could make the words "your" and "vote" and "count" bold as well.  Though perhaps that too is confusing so maybe the entire sentence should be in bold.  Yes, that's sarcasm you're detecting.  I think it is fairly evident what is intended here.

Comment: @Neil: I totally agree (That wasn't sarcasm)

Comment: As a point of reference, there isn't anything at all in bold in any of the tag descriptions.