# Electorate badge info doesn't make sense

Tags: discussion, support, badges, electorate-badge

The information for the [Electorate badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) doesn't make sense. It says:

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

If I vote on 600 questions, won't that already be 100%? I assume that it is supposed to say "vote on 600 questions **and answers** and 25% of total votes are on questions." Shouldn't it be re-worded? Apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: Pretty sure this has been asked before, but to clarify until the dupe is found: You need 600 votes on _only questions_ and those 600 votes need to make up _at least_ 25% of your total vote count. So if you vote 600 times and they're all on questions, you'll get it. If you vote 2400 times, and 1800 of those are on answers, you still get the badge because 600 are on questions and those votes are 25% of your total votes.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271521/2607247) by Martijn Peters helps make it more clear what the badge means.

Comment: For an example, note that [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity) does not have the electorate badge, since his voting percentage on questions is too low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in order to receive the Electorate badge you should vote on 600 questions - votes on answers don't count (except for the 25% of course). So the current wording is correct. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/295232) on Meta SE for a full list of badges with extended descriptions.